# Template Argument Deduction Broken in Clang 6 for Temporary Objects

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++17, clang++

Template argument deduction appears to be broken in Clang 6 for temporary objects.

g++ 8.1.0 compiles and runs the example correctly.

Clang 6.0.0 and 6.0.2 both error at the indicated line with this message:

```
error: expected unqualified-id
    Print{1,"foo"s,2};  /********** Broken in Clang **********/
```

All Other lines work correctly.

The behavior is the same in both cases whether `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++2a` is used.

[The Clang c++ Status Page](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) indicates that template argument deduction was implemented as of Clang 5 (P0091R3, P0512R0).

Is this a bug? Are there workarounds (e.g. compiler flags, **not code changes**)?

example:

```
template<class ...Ts>
void print(Ts...ts){ (( cout << ... << ts )); }
template<class ...Ts>
struct Print {
    Print(Ts...ts){ (( cout << ... << ts )); }
};

int main(){
    Print{1,"foo"s,2}; /********** Broken in Clang **********/
    Print<int,string,int>{1,"foo"s,2};
    auto p1 = Print{1,"foo"s,2};
    Print p2{1,"foo"s,2};
    print(1,"foo"s,2);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is Clang bug [34091](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34091).

Luckily, it is already fixed, and the trunk build of Clang [compiles this without issue](https://godbolt.org/g/zpLDVE).

As far as I know, however, there is currently no way to work around this without code changes, short of upgrading to the next Clang release whenever that comes out.